# are multiple statements inside an if the same as multiple ifs?

Tags: c++, c, performance

is

```
if(a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) { return; }
```

the same as

```
if(a == 0) { return; }

if(b == 0) { return; }

if(c == 0) { return; }
```

or

```
if(a == 0) { return; }

else if(b == 0) { return; }

else if(c == 0) { return; }
```

I want to write fast code and am interested in how different these statements are interpreted into assembly instructions usually.

Comment: [Use godbolt](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: The second and third are equivalent to each other, and to `if(a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0) { return; }`. They return if any one of the three is zero, while the first returns when all three are zero.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik They are equivalent only because of the `return` in the bodies of each `if` block. With other content, they may very well not be equivalent.

Comment: And you may want to read about `short circuiting`.

Comment: That's probably the wrong place to optimize your code. The compiler will do it better. Enable compiler optimization and let it do.

Comment: according to godbolt, the first one generates 17 lines of assembly vs 20 for the other 2

Comment: You're micro-optimizing, don't do that. Concentrate on writing good, clean, readable and maintainable code. first and foremost. Then if the program doesn't live up to the requirements you have, you measure, benchmark and profile to find the top two (or possibly three) bottlenecks, and work on optimizing them (with *plenty* of documentation and comments). I doubt something like this will ever come in on even the top-ten.

Comment: Oh and when benchmarking and measuring, always build with optimizations enabled.

Comment: For me the compiler produces exactly the same 4 lines of code: https://godbolt.org/z/qLDsZW

Comment: @orORorOR -- As stated before, looking at small `if` statements does nothing for program speed if your program uses inefficient algorithms, loops, etc.  If you have a triple-nested `for` loop somewhere, looping a million times, when you could use a different data structure, presort the items, whatever, thus reducing this time, that is far more worth it than trying to optimize an `if` statement.

Comment: @orORorOR As the first one isn't equivalent to the other two, it is irrelevant how many assembler statements it produces. If it had `||` instead of `&&` in both places it would be the same. As it doesn't, it isn't.

Answer (score 14):

```
if(a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) { return; }
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if(a == 0)
  if(b == 0)
    if(c == 0)
      return;
```

Whereas, these two:

```
//1
if(a == 0) { return; }
if(b == 0) { return; }
if(c == 0) { return; }
//2
if(a == 0) { return; }
else if(b == 0) { return; }
else if(c == 0) { return; }
```

are equivalent to
`if( a==0 || b == 0 || c == 0){ return; }`.

Comment: How is if(a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) { return; } equivalent to if(a == 0)
  if(b == 0)
    if(c == 0)
      return 0;?? One is a void function the other one is returning an int???

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above

```
if(a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) { return; }
```

is the same as

```
if(a == 0) 
 if(b == 0) 
  if(c == 0) 
    return;
```

and

```
if(a == 0) { return; }

else if(b == 0) { return; }

else if(c == 0) { return; }
```

is equal to

```
if(a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0) { return; }
```

but only in this example, because we return nothing in every if state.

Comment: return 0 is not the same as return

Comment: thanks @armagedescu, my mistake, did not double check before posting